# FOSUserBundle/Symfony2: Force logout of a user given a user (not the currently logged in user)

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Whenever I edit a user's role, the user needs to logout and log back in to see the changes. There's no problem when promoting a user as they just won't see the extra permissions until signing in again. However, when a demotion was to occur, a user will still keep its existing role which impose security risks. Imagine revoking admin user on a rogue employee, and still have them be able to do anything (eg. sabotaging the system) until they log out!

Is it possible to invalidate all sessions or tokens that are related to a specific user? If there is another way to dynamically update the roles of a user without logging them out, I would love to hear it!

Just to make it clear, I'm not trying to invalidate the currently logged in user's session/token.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony stores serialized token object under `_security_match_firewall_name` key in session. You can unserialize it, filter role and then save it again. For reading/saving session values you can use `PdoSessionStorage`. You may have to create an extra table for tracking users session.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. Is it possible to add an extra column to the session table to store the user id that's associated with the session id that PdoSessionStorage uses? As well, how would I get the token object given the session id? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To do that you may have to modify PdoSessionStorage class. I think it is better to create an interactive login listener and in `onSecurityInteractiveLogin` method you get the session id and save it in a table, say `user_sessions`.

Comment: That's probably the best way to go to store it in another db. I'm still lost on how to go from the session value stored in db to a security token and back.

Comment: Just issue `var_dump($_SESSION)` in on of your controller to check the session data format of logged in session. This session data is stored at session_value field of the session table (if you have implemented PdoSessionStorage by following [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html). The data is base_64 encoded. So you have to decode it.You may want to look at the [implementation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/PdoSessionStorage.php).

Comment: So once I base_64 decode it, how would I unserialize the string to a session object so I could grab the security token from it? Sorry for asking so many questions. Maybe if you can point out which file uses sessionRead(...) from PdoSessionStorage, I can figure it out myself.

Comment: Session read and write is done in [ContextListener.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php) at `handle` and `onKernelResponse` methods respectively.