# symfony2 disconnect/logout one user (not the current user)

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle

In my application, i do need to disconnect a user programatically.
Not the current user, but another one, knowing its id. I am using FOSUserBundle but I guess this could be good for any provider.

Token and sessions are relative to the current user and stored on its computer I guess.

So, how can I do that?

There is som related post here but the response does not match the request : [FOSUserBundle/Symfony2: Force logout of a user given a user (not the currently logged in user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630032/fosuserbundle-symfony2-force-logout-of-a-user-given-a-user-not-the-currently-l)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only when you are **NOT** using native php session handler (which is default in `symfony`). In this case you don't know other users session ids.

The way you could do that is using database as your session storage - there's a [howto](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) on `symfony.com`. Once you have session stored in database destroying user's session is just deleting proper row from database.

And yes - `FosUserBundle` has nothing to do here, it is not specific to this bundle

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, every time a page is loaded the user from the session is compared to the corresponding user on the database. If the comparison returns a false then the user is forced to log in again.

FOSUserBundle serializes a bunch of user data to be stored on the session including the `enabled` field. This mean that if you set the users `enabled` status to `false` then on the next page load the session `enabled` won't be equal to the database `enabled` meaning the users aren't equal leading to the user needing to log in again.

To do it without FOSUSerBundle you would just need to include some sort of `enabled` field in your users admin system and then check that on every page load in your serialize (or in the `isEqualTo` as shown [in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-user-class) ) and then you can log people out on next page load.

Comment: ok. So maybe adding the roles to the serializer would work? I'm gonna try that